# The genre system in django

Tags: python, django

I'm making a genre system on django based on the videos. I came across a problem that when I select a certain genre and click on the find button, I am thrown a link of the type '/filter/?genre=2', but the problem is that the found books are not displayed, I know for sure that they are, the problem is specifically in the template.The genres themselves also disappear from the sidebar, but the header tag and some others remain. I can't figure out what the problem is.

url

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', index, name='index'),
    path("filter/", views.FilterBookView.as_view(), name='filter'),
    path('allbook', AllBookView.as_view(), name='allbook'),
    # path('addbook', AddBookView.as_view(), name='addbook'),
    # path('register', RegisterView.as_view(), name='reg'),
    # path('login', LoginView.as_view(), name='login'),
    # path('logout', LogoutView.as_view(), name='logout'),
    # path('info/<int:id>', MoreInfoView.as_view(), name='more_info'),
    # path('profile', profileview, name='profile'),
    # path('password-change', ChangePasswordView.as_view(), name='change_pass'),
    # path('like/<int:pk>', LikeView, name='like_book'),
    # path('random/', views.random_book, name='random_book'),
    # path('review/<int:pk>', AddReview.as_view(), name='review'),

]
```

views.py

```
class FilterBookView(GenreView, ListView):
    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = BookModel.objects.filter(
            Q(genres__in=self.request.GET.getlist("genre"))
        )
        return queryset

class GenreView:

    def get_genres(self):
        return Genre.objects.all()

class AllBookView(View):


    def get(self, request):
        allbook = BookModel.objects.all()
        view_genres = GenreView.get_genres(self)
        return render(request, 'bookapp/bookmodel_list.html', context={
            'allbook': allbook,
            'viewgenre': view_genres,
        })
```

models.py

```
class Genre(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('Имя', max_length=100)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Жанр"
        verbose_name_plural = "Жанры"


class BookModel(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name='Название')
    creator = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name='creator', null=True)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name='автор')
    contentbook = models.TextField(verbose_name='Содержание')
    picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/', verbose_name='Обложка')
    price = models.IntegerField(null=True, verbose_name='Цена')
    price_rent = models.IntegerField(null=True, verbose_name='Аренда')
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='book_post', verbose_name='лайкнули')
    genres = models.ManyToManyField(Genre, verbose_name='жанры')
```

html

```
<header></header>
<div></div>  (Внутренности этих тегов надеюсь не так важны, но они выводятся)
<form action="{% url 'filter' %}" method="get">
    <div class="left-side my-4">
        <h3 class="sear-head editContent">Жанры</h3>
        <ul class="w3layouts-box-list" style="list-style-type: none; padding: 0">
            {% for genre in viewgenre %}
                <li class="editContent" style="list-style-type: none; padding: 0">
                    <input type="checkbox" class="checked" name="genre" value="{{ genre.id }}">
                    <span class="span editContent">{{ genre.name }}</span>
                </li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- // preference -->
    <!-- discounts -->

    <button type="submit">Найти</button>
</form>
```

Comment: share your urls.py as well

Comment: Added url.py from my project

Comment: for /filter/ you are using FilterBookView and I cannot see FilterView in your views.py

Comment: I'm sorry, didn 't see . Added